# Show that if $S \cup \{ \neg A\} \vdash B$ then $S \vdash A$

Tags: logic, natural-deduction

As mentioned in the title. I need to show that

$S \vdash A$ when I know that $S \cup \{ \neg A \} \vdash B$

And I can't use completeness theorem here.

I know I can say

$S \vdash \neg A \rightarrow B$

due to what we know. However I don't see how thats helpful. I have also tried to show that $S \cup \{ \neg A \}$ is inconsitent by trying to deduct $\neg B$ or A from it but no success thus far.

Edit.

Just to make sure this is bit more clear as I think the initial version might be bit messy.

So let S be a group of propositional formulas and A a propositional formula. Lets assume that for all propositional formulas B, $S \cup \{ \neg A \} \vdash B$. Now show without completeness theorem that $S \vdash A$.

Comment: It is not true... You have to check $B$: maybe it must be different ($\bot$ ?).

Comment: Are you aware of the definition of *inconsistent* set $S$ of formulas ?

Comment: What you mean by 'check B'? Also I assume I am familiar with definition of inconsistent set S of formulas but not entirely sure as English is not my native language.

Comment: Take $S=\varnothing$ and $B=\lnot A$, then easily $S\cup\{\lnot A\}\vdash B$, but unless $A$ is a tautology, $S$ cannot prove $A$.

Comment: Are you sure that it isn't possible to prove A? There is obviously a possibility that there is a typo and that it can't be solved but I do doubt it a bit.

Comment: @E.K.: What was missing was the "for all propositional formulas $B$" part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A theory proves all propositional formulas if and only if it is inconsistent. As such, the assumption that $S \cup \{ \neg A \} \vdash B$ for all formulae $B$ implies that $S \cup \{ \neg A \}$ is inconsistent. Now either $S$ is consistent or it is inconsistent:

- If $S$ is inconsistent, then $S \vdash A$.
- If $S$ is consistent then so is $S \cup \{ C \}$ for any $C$ for which $S \vdash C$. Since $S \cup \{ \neg A \}$ is inconsistent, it follows that $S \nvdash \neg A$, so that $S \vdash A$ by completeness.

In either case we see that, $S \vdash A$.

Comment: Been reading this answer and some materials and while this is obviously correct answer I think this could be done little bit more efficient by using some theorems. We have a theorem which says the following are equivalent 1) $S \vdash A$ 2) $S \cup \{\neg A\}$ is inconsistent. If we use this wouldn't the second case be unnecessary?

Comment: @E.K. Yes, if you have already proved that then there's no need to re-prove it in your proof of this result